# SharePoint 2013 - Managed property value does not update

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, bdc, sharepoint-search, sharepoint2010-bcs

I have configure SharePoint Search with line of Business Content Source (BCS).
Create Few Managed Property with this BCS.
Records is crawling successfully however managed mapped property value does not updated.
And one more thing, I have database in which I have 5 records however SharePoint crawling 7 records instead of 5. Two (2) of them are coming with null values.
Please help me to fix this situation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Got the Solution.

Above issue is resolved by adding ListElement and ItemElement in mapping of crawled properties box.